# Indy 10 and setting socket options

Tags: delphi, indy10

Maybe the solution to this is very simple and I'm just too dumb to see it.
I need to recompile an old application with Indy 10 and there's this line that used to be

```
inUDPServer.Binding.SetSockOpt(Id_IPPROTO_IP, Id_IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, PChar(@mreq), SizeOf(mreq));
```

but the new TIdSocketHandle.SetSockOpt takes 3 integers.
Now how am I supposed to provide the ip_mreq? Just passing the imr_multiaddr.S_addr results in an #10014 Error - Buffer fault.
Maybe one of you guys has an idea.

Cheers Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `TIdSocketHandle.AddMulticastMembership()` method instead (if your version of Indy 10 does not have that method available, then you will have to update to a newer snapshot first), eg:

```
inUDPServer.Binding.AddMulticastMembership('Group IP address');
```

It adds the `TIdSocketHandle.IP` address to the membership of the specified Group IP.  IPs can be specified as either IPv4 or IPv6, depending on the setting of the `TIdSocketHandle.IPVersion` property.

Alternatively, consider using the `TIdIPMCastServer` and `TIdIPMCastClient` components instead of `TIdUDPServer` directly.